# Issues with linked list and pointers (C)

Tags: c, linked-list

I am writing a C program to sort a linked list according to the largest values. I met an issue whereby the program just hangs when the program reached "prevPtr->next = headPtr". 
I want the prevPtr->next to equate to headPtr, if the sum of prevPtr is larger than the sum of headPtr, however the program just hangs there.

compareNodes() function is used to compare the nodes to see if newNode has the same name as any other structs in the linked list, then it will add in the sum.

sortSimilarNodes() function is used to sort the nodes according to the sum of each struct.

The struct is here below:

```
  struct purchase {
        char name[30];
        double sum;

        struct purchase * next;
    } ;

        LOG * compareNodes(LOG * headPtr, char * name, char * price){
        .
        .
        .
            while (curPtr != NULL) {
                    if (strcmp(newNode->name, curPtr->name)==0) {
                        curPtr->sum += newNode->sum;
                        free(newNode);
                        similar = 1;

                        break;

                    }
                    //advance to next target
                    prevPtr = curPtr; 
                    curPtr = curPtr->next;
                }
                /*if (curPtr == NULL){
                    if(strcmp(newNode->name, prevPtr->name)==0){
                        prevPtr->sum += newNode->sum;
                        free(newNode);
                        similar = 1;
                    }
                }*/

                if (similar == 1){
                    headPtr = sortSimilarNodes(curPtr, headPtr);

                }
                else{
                    headPtr = sortNodes(newNode, headPtr);
                }

                return headPtr;
    }

    LOG * sortSimilarNodes(LOG * newPtr, LOG * headPtr){
        LOG * curPtr;
        LOG * prevPtr;

        if(headPtr->sum < newPtr->sum){

            newPtr->next = headPtr;
            return newPtr;
        }

        prevPtr = headPtr;
        curPtr = headPtr->next;
        while (curPtr == NULL){

        }
        while (curPtr != NULL){

            if(strcmp(curPtr->name, newPtr->name)==0){
                break;
            }
            prevPtr = curPtr; 
            curPtr = curPtr->next;
        } 
        return headPtr;

    }
```

[This is the output of the program.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9Mj4.png)
Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "just hangs"?

Comment: @o_weisman when i run it in the console, it goes into the if statement, but it does not proceed with the program and it just hangs at that assignment of pointer.

Comment: First, do you terminate your linked list with a NULL pointer? Are you sure your `curPtr` will eventually be NULL.

Comment: Maybe all it takes is to remove the `while (curPtr == NULL) {}` loop, which is either a non-op (when `curPtr` isn't null) or an infinite loop (when `curPtr` is null).

Comment: Are you running it with a debugger? How do you know where it hangs?

Comment: @Amjad yup, i have initialised my linked list headpointer with NULL. curPtr will eventually be NULL when it reaches the last struct of the linked list.

Comment: @MOehm i tried that but it still hangs.

Comment: What is `newPtr` supposed to be in the sorting function? There are no new nodes when you sort; after soring, it's just the same nodes rearranged.

Comment: @MOehm the newNode is found in the ... section of the function compareNodes() function, so the nodes will be sorted.

Comment: @droptable can you post all the code so we can debug it?

Comment: Your print out only tells you that it reached that location, not that it hangs there.What M Oehm said is true, you have to remove that line as it is obviously an endless loop if curPtr is null.

Comment: This code is near the end of the sample given.  `curPtr = headPtr->next; while (curPtr == NULL){ }`.   It will result in an infinite loop of `headPtr->next` is ever `NULL`

Comment: Yes, please do tidy up your code before you post it. For example you say that "sortSimilarNodes() function is used to sort the nodes according to the sum of each struct", but you compare strings with `strcmp`in that function.

Comment: @Amjad i will add u guys into a chatroom

Comment: The chatroom is opened by my friend Kode.Error404.

Comment: @Peter I have removed it, but it still couldn't work.

Comment: @MOehm yup of course, i think the code isnt clear enough as i did not show the entire code, please enter this chatroom to see the entire code. 
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132072/room-for-kode-error404-and-amjad

Comment: @o_weisman I have already removed it, it is still the same. please enter this chatroom to see the entire code. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132072/room-for-kode-error404-and-amjad

Comment: Unless your program creates PNG files - and it doesn't look it should -, please copy the output into your question as text.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your code, because you haven't posted all of it, but you seem to have some misconceptions about linked lists. In particular:

- There is no need for new nodes unless you really add new nodes to the list. That also means that you don't call `malloc` except when adding nodes. (There's no `malloc` in your code, but a suspicious `free` in your comparison function. Comparing does not involve creating or destroying anything; it just means to look what is already there.)
- A corollary to the first point is that there should be no nodes in an empty list, not even dummy nodes. An empty list is a list whose `head` is `NULL`. Make sure that you initialise all head pointers before creating a new list:

  ```
  LOG *head = NULL;      // empty list
  ```
- When you sort the list, the order of the list has changed and the old head is invalid. You cater for that by returning the new head:

  ```
  head = sort(head);
  ```

  But that seems redundant and it also seems to imply that the two pointers can be different. That's not the case, because the old pointer will point somehwre in the sorted list, not necessarily at its head. It's probably better to pass the head pointer's address in order to avoid confusion:

  ```
  sort(&head);
  ```

Sorting linked lists can be tricky. One straightforward way is selection sort: Find the node with the highest value, remove it from the original list and add it at the front of a new list. Repeat until there are no more nodes in the original list.

Adding a new node `n` at the front of a list given by `head` is easy:

```
n->next = head;
head= n;
```

Adding a new node at the end of a list that is given by `head` is a bit more involved:

```
LOG **p = &head;

while (*p) p = &(*p)->next;
*p = n;
n->next = NULL;
```

Here, `p` is the address of the pointer that points to the current node, `*p`. After walking the list, that address is either the address of the `head` node (when the list is empty) or the address of the `next` pointer of the precedig node.

You could achieve something similar by keeping a `prev` pointer, but the pointer-to-pointer solution means that you don't have to treat the cases where there is no previous node specially at the cost of some extra `&` and `*` operators.

With that, your sorting routine becomes:

```
void sortByName(LOG **head)
{
    LOG *sorted = NULL;

    while (*head) {
        LOG **p = head;      // auxiliary pointer to walk the list
        LOG **max = head;    // pointer to current maximum
        LOG *n;              // maximum node

        while (*p) {
            if (strcmp((*p)->name, (*max)->name) > 0) max = p;
            p = &(*p)->next;
        }

        n = *max;
        *max = (*max)->next;

        n->next = sorted;
        sorted = n;
    }

    *head = sorted;
}
```

If you want to sort by sum, change the comparison to:

```
            if ((*p)->sum > (*max)->sum) max = p;
```

Call the function like this:

```
LOG *head = NULL;

insert(&head, "apple", 2.3);
insert(&head, "pear", 1.7);
insert(&head, "strawberry", 2.2);
insert(&head, "orange", 3.2);
insert(&head, "plum", 2.1);

sortByName(&head); 
print(head);
destroy(&head);
```

with the `insert`, `destroy` and `print` functions for completeness:

```
void insert(LOG **head, const char *name, double sum)
{
    LOG *n = malloc(sizeof(*n));

    if (n) {
        snprintf(n->name, sizeof(n->name), "%s", name);
        n->sum = sum;

        n->next = *head;
        *head = n;
    }    
}

void destroy(LOG **head)
{
    LOG *n = *head;

    while (n) {
        LOG *p = n;

        n = n->next;
        free(p);
    }

    *head = NULL;
}

void print(LOG *l)
{
    while (l) {
        printf("%s: %g\n", l->name, l->sum);
        l = l->next;
    }

    puts("");
}
```